# Big load (lag) while loading page because of images

Tags: javascript, image, lag

I'm facing this issue right now. When my page loads up (DOM) I call a function which returns 1880 images and those images are being stored in steam server.

[image: big image load]
[image: image preview]

Those images are being added to my DOM just after the callback which returns me array response with 1880 elements (links to images and some info). After the callback those images are being built into DOM as mentioned before.

This method cause a big LAG on website (over 20 seconds freezing). Is there any option to run something? How to deal with this?

Comment: Instead of loading the images when the page loads, can you load the images only as the user needs them?

Comment: Thanks Jason, but user needs it the same moment when page loads. It could be done with appending (as scrolling) but the thing is that page is full of 30x30 images and coming with 1920px resolution will cause the same problem..

Comment: Are these like icon images?  Another option is to have 1 large image with all of the small images in it.  Then you display it using positioning.

Comment: @Sandra How so ? Let's say the page can hold 120 of those images at once, if you implement an asynchronous solution (loading the images with Ajax as the user scrolls), I am utterly certain that there will be a big improvement in the page-load time.

Comment: @nurdyguy is referring to a sprite sheet, you can google that if it'll answer your problem. The idea is that loading 1 large image is much faster than 1800 small images.

Comment: thats not the static images and with data coming on every of them (hover/click effects). But its kind of icon images. Website full of these images.

Comment: @JasonFry Couldn't she/he use an image compressor ? and caching.

Comment: You could also use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) instead of putting click events on each image. That should increase performance, too.

Comment: as I mentioned before there are many dynamic small images and not static images which can be made to one big image and be used as sprite. and with large monitor user have to see at least 600 those images at once.

Comment: @Sandra See [this](https://xkeshi.github.io/image-compressor/) library.

Comment: Where are you now ? I am just curious since this is an interesting problem.

Comment: okay so I decided to make something you all suggested. So I've added all the images to one big image with the coordinates of every image in JSON (everything was made on server side, and not client). But its still takes some time to load such a big image. P.S. images is being added by downloading them to server and building one big image of them (sprite sheet)

Answer (score 2):

a solution would be to only load the images you need. I highly doubt that the user can see 1880 images at once.

After you page loads you can use any framework to send an asycronous js request to you server for the rest of your images.

Example:

-When the page loads there are only 10 images (lets say that is how much the user sees at once on the screen)

-When the user starts to scroll he should see new images. So onscroll you launch your ajax request for 10 new images.

-Repeat whenever the user scrolls

Of course, depending on what you try to do the steps above need to be adapted / optimesed differently

Comment: Thats the solution but not what I need, what If I need to display 30x30 images on whole website and the user comes with 1920px resolution. The problem is the same - many images.

Comment: "the user comes with 1920px resolution" what do you mean by that? Does the user have a ton of small images on which he can click to display a 1920px res version of the image?

Comment: My website is full of those images (30x30 with only 1px margin between them) and monitor with 1920px resolution should hold ±700 images maybe? So the result is the same - lag

Comment: You wouldn't lose anything if you implemented that solution as well. You will have to tackle this problem in many different ways, if each way removes 2 seconds, you will have done a great job.

Comment: If all of your images are small, you could use some sort of compression to send a single file and then divide it at the front end (could be better than sending 800 separate http requests). Also, creating the DOM elements dynamically also increases lag. EDIT: I mean that if you set a fixed number of images inside the file you get an improvement over determining the number of images you need and the configuration of your DOM dynamically, even if you still send 1000+ requests (even though you should avoid doing so)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest getting 3 sprite sheets at different resolutions, load the best one for the user's screen size, and use event delegation to put click events on each sprite. That should address everything you've mentioned in your question and in the comments.

Comment: 1880 different and not static images. And what images to load depends of user.

Comment: That doesn't matter, you can still use sprite sheets.

Comment: how come? You mean download the images on page load and put them all in one sprite sheet for example and keep the positions of every image in array or something?

Comment: You'll need to google 'sprite sheet'. It's a single image with all your images on it. You use jQuery or JavaScript to put the correct image in the correct spot on your website.